# Moving Route53 hosted zones to another Account's Route53 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have almost 19 Hosted Zones and they all have almost max 34 records set count. They were in the account `mhlabs` and I moved them to account `evercam`.

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider) I need to updated the NS records as well and I..

From mhlabs account's evercam.io hosted zones.. I copied the NS, 4 records and copied them to evercam account's evercam.io and it's been 48Hours.

When I click on the radio button of evercam.io NS records are the old ones, but when I go inside the NS records are the new one Which I added.

How long it will take to change it?

Also written in Route53

> The four name servers that route 52 assigned to the hosted zone if you
>   change the name servers in the NS record for hosted zone, Route53
>   doesn't change the assigned name server

Comment: Are they all private hosted zones and domains hosted in 3rd party services?

Comment: They are not private, all are public but yes domains are being used by third parties, in AWS they are mostly pointers, cname or redirects.

Comment: As you are moving all into the 2nd account, have you updated 4 NS values on each newly created hosted zone?

Comment: @Leondkr Yes, I have updated the 4NS values while going into the hosted zone and NS record I have updated the nameservers to the old ones. but when they will take effect? its been almost 2 days now

Answer (score 1):

Although you’re already using Route 53 as the DNS provider for your domain, when you create a new hosted zone, Route 53 randomly assigns four new nameservers to that zone.

In order to use the new hosted zone with your domain you’ll need to update your domains nameservers to use the nameservers provided by the new hosted zone.

You can follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider) for setting Route 53 as your DNS provider. It is important to note that although this part of the tutorial starts with “To begin using Amazon Route 53 as the DNS service for a domain”, you will follow the same steps to update the name servers when you migrate hosted zones.

Comment: I tried to update NS records from the older to the new, but its written that if you will change NS values , Route53 will not change them?

Answer (score 0):

When you move into your 2nd account, remember to update your NS record's values.

From 2nd account's Route 53, there are 4 new values from NS type record:

```
mydomain.com | NS | <4 rows Route53 new values>
```

From your 3rd party hosting domain services, replace your hosting domain's NS values with **Route53 new values above**.

At last, use any DNS checking service to check if the change has been made successfully or not.

```
https://dnschecker.org/
```